# Why is Gurobi returning MIP solution with gap of 0 which is not close to the actual optimal solution?

Tags: optimization, gurobi

Using the below code and the following two .csv files, Gurobi returns an optimal solution of 62.42 when the parameter SET_SOME_VARS is set to 0, but returns a much better solution (of 12.32) when it is set to 1 (as shown in log files below the code).  But setting it to 1 is just forcing one feasible solution for the problem, so why is the version without these constraints finding a much worse "optimal" solution?  The MIP solution ends with a gap of 0 in both cases.

Thanks in advance for any insights on this!

(Census_Population_1970.csv can be obtained via this google sheet):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yS7FWRrknAEUnQzDXu1Fv0eiY2UplY_ElQleXcyMqOQ/edit?usp=sharing

(moo93.csv can be obtained via this google sheet):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NkuxVslk9PhpFv0eujiNvnOaBK7nWf6ekexn3dkcsjk/edit?usp=sharing

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(Matrix)
library('gurobi')

SET_SOME_VARS <- 0 # setting to 1 forces some of the decision variables to take on certain pre-set value
                   # setting to 0 lets Gurobi optimize these and the other variables

total_reps <- 435
num_states <- 50
obj_weight_pairwise <- 94
obj_weight_range <- 100-obj_weight_pairwise

data <- read.csv("Census_Population_1970.csv") 
total_pop <- sum(data$Population)
data$quota <- data$Population/total_pop*total_reps  # the # of seats the state should get under continuous reps by 

###########################
# SET UP DECISION VARIABLES
###########################   

num_x_vars <- num_states
num_v_vars <- (num_states-1)*num_states/2
num_y_vars <- 1
num_vars <- num_x_vars + num_v_vars + num_y_vars

model <- list()

#setting up the x vars 
for (i in 1:num_x_vars) 
{
  model$vtype[i] = 'I'     
  model$varnames[i] = paste0('X', i)
  model$obj[i] = 0         
  model$lb[i] = 1          
}

#setting up the v vars 
for (i in 1:num_v_vars) 
{
  var_index <- num_x_vars + i
  model$vtype[var_index] = 'C'     
  model$varnames[var_index] = paste0('V', i)
  model$obj[var_index] = obj_weight_pairwise  #the weight given to the v vars
  model$lb[var_index] = 0
}

# setting up the y vars
for (i in 1:num_y_vars) 
{
  var_index <- num_x_vars + num_v_vars + i
  model$vtype[var_index] = 'C'
  model$varnames[var_index] = paste0('Y', i)
  model$obj[var_index] = obj_weight_range  #the weight given to the y var
  model$lb[var_index] = 0    
}

###########################
# SET UP CONSTRAINTS
###########################

# Constraint 1: sum of x vars = 435
model$A <- matrix(c(rep(1, num_x_vars), rep(0, num_v_vars), rep(0, num_y_vars)), nrow = 1, byrow = FALSE)  # constraints of type labeled constraint 1 above (which is just 1 constraint)
model$sense <- '='
model$rhs <- total_reps

#TESTING: activating the following code chunk returns a feasible solution with a better objective value (12.32), 
# compared to the objective value of 62.42 the optimization returns when it is de-activated   
if(SET_SOME_VARS) {
# Constraints to fix x vars at certain values given in the following .csv file (obtained by a weighting of 93 and 7 instead of 94 and 6)
moo93 <- read.csv("moo93.csv") 
B <- spMatrix(num_x_vars, num_vars,
              i = (1:num_x_vars),
              j = (1:num_x_vars),
              x = rep(1, num_x_vars))
model$A     <- rbind(model$A,B)
model$sense <- c(model$sense, rep('=', num_x_vars))
model$rhs <- c(model$rhs, moo93$MOO93)
}

# Constraints to set up the v and y variables to take on the intended objective values 
v_index <- 1
qc_index <- 1
cumulative_quadcon <- list()
temp_list <- list()

for (i in 1:(num_states-1))     
{
  for (j in (i+1):num_states)
  {
    temp_list$Qc <- spMatrix(num_vars, num_vars, c(i, j), c(i, j), c((data$quota[i])^(-2), -(data$quota[j])^(-2)))
    temp_list$q <- sparseVector(c(-(data$quota[i])^(-2), -(data$quota[j])^(-2), -1), c(i,j,num_x_vars+v_index), num_vars)
    temp_list$rhs <- 0
    cumulative_quadcon[[qc_index]] <- temp_list
    
    qc_index <- qc_index + 1
    temp_list$Qc <- spMatrix(num_vars, num_vars, num_vars, i, -1/data$quota[i])
    temp_list$q <- sparseVector(1/data$quota[j], j, num_vars)
    temp_list$rhs <- 0
    cumulative_quadcon[[qc_index]] <- temp_list
    
    qc_index <- qc_index + 1
    temp_list$Qc <- spMatrix(num_vars, num_vars, c(i, j), c(i, j), c(-(data$quota[i])^(-2), (data$quota[j])^(-2)))
    temp_list$q <- sparseVector(c(-(data$quota[i])^(-2), -(data$quota[j])^(-2), -1), c(i,j,num_x_vars+v_index), num_vars)
    temp_list$rhs <- 0
    cumulative_quadcon[[qc_index]] <- temp_list
    
    qc_index <- qc_index + 1
    temp_list$Qc <- spMatrix(num_vars, num_vars, num_vars, j, -1/data$quota[j])
    temp_list$q <- sparseVector(1/data$quota[i], i, num_vars)
    temp_list$rhs <- 0
    cumulative_quadcon[[qc_index]] <- temp_list
    
    qc_index <- qc_index + 1
    v_index <- v_index + 1
  }
}

model$quadcon <- cumulative_quadcon
model$modelsense  <- 'min' 

params<-list()
params$NonConvex <- 2

# solve model
result <- gurobi(model, params)

if (result$status == 'OPTIMAL') {
  data$reps <- result$x[1:num_states]
} else {
  cat('Optimization finished with status',result$status)
}
```

The Gurobi log file for SET_SOME_VARS <- 0 is:

```
Gurobi 9.1.2 (win64, R) logging started Wed Dec 22 20:31:58 2021

Academic license - for non-commercial use only - expires 2022-02-12
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.2 build v9.1.2rc0 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 1 rows, 1276 columns and 50 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xf16eb2e8
Model has 4900 quadratic constraints
Variable types: 1226 continuous, 50 integer (0 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  QMatrix range    [5e-04, 2e+00]
  QLMatrix range   [5e-04, 2e+00]
  Objective range  [6e+00, 9e+01]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [4e+02, 4e+02]
Presolve added 2450 rows and 50 columns
Presolve time: 0.12s
Presolved: 5151 rows, 1377 columns, 17750 nonzeros
Presolved model has 100 bilinear constraint(s)
Variable types: 1277 continuous, 100 integer (0 binary)

Root relaxation: objective 1.867190e+00, 239 iterations, 0.01 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0    1.86719    0  155          -    1.86719      -     -    0s
     0     0    9.25498    0  138          -    9.25498      -     -    0s
     0     0    9.26378    0  143          -    9.26378      -     -    0s
     0     0    9.26378    0  142          -    9.26378      -     -    0s
     0     0    9.26988    0  142          -    9.26988      -     -    0s
     0     0    9.27086    0  142          -    9.27086      -     -    0s
     0     0    9.27086    0  142          -    9.27086      -     -    0s
H    0     0                    132928.48289    9.27086   100%     -    0s
H    0     0                    122313.23902    9.27086   100%     -    0s
     0     2    9.27086    0  139 122313.239    9.27086   100%     -    0s
H   31    40                    51799.876166    9.27086   100%  50.9    0s
H   37    40                    47379.031535    9.27086   100%  45.5    0s
H   75    80                    43012.927608    9.27086   100%  78.3    1s
H  163   168                    41021.730754    9.27086   100%  66.4    1s
H  210   215                    40017.605994    9.27086   100%  60.6    1s
H  250   259                    36476.831033    9.27086   100%  58.4    1s
H  605   565                    24138.541776    9.27086   100%  67.3    2s
H  673   606                    20317.722108    9.27086   100%  68.1    3s
H  741   527                    2156.8361423    9.27086   100%  68.2    3s
H  795   352                     147.4166759    9.27086  93.7%  67.1    3s
H 1072   407                      62.4183404    9.29574  85.1%  67.0    5s
  1105   429   19.23422  102   94   62.41834   10.23145  83.6%  65.0   10s

Explored 1126 nodes (75074 simplex iterations) in 13.42 seconds
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 10: 62.4183 147.417 2156.84 ... 47379

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 6.241834040384e+01, best bound 6.241834040384e+01, gap 0.0000%
```

The above returns an optimal solution of 62.42.
However, the Gurobi log file for SET_SOME_VARS <- 1 shows an optimal solution of 12.32:

```
Gurobi 9.1.2 (win64, R) logging started Wed Dec 22 20:30:18 2021

Academic license - for non-commercial use only - expires 2022-02-12
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.2 build v9.1.2rc0 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 51 rows, 1276 columns and 100 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x5cd17a23
Model has 4900 quadratic constraints
Variable types: 1226 continuous, 50 integer (0 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  QMatrix range    [5e-04, 2e+00]
  QLMatrix range   [5e-04, 2e+00]
  Objective range  [6e+00, 9e+01]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 4e+02]
Presolve removed 51 rows and 1276 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed

Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 0.01 seconds
Thread count was 1 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 1: 12.3166 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 1.231664731786e+01, best bound 1.231664731786e+01, gap 0.0000%
```

Comment: Please post the Gurobi logs so that we better understand the issue.

Comment: Hi Greg, I just appended the two log files at the bottom of my original post. Thanks

Comment: Update: It seems that this problem occurs with version 9.1.2, but has been fixed in version 9.5.0